# Setting open_basedir on Media Temple

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mediatemple

I'm currently getting an `open_basedir restriction` error on my CakePHP application running on Media Temple. (site number and domain changed for purpose of question).

I've read the docs here: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/514/How+do+I+set+the+path+for+open_basedir%3F#gs for how to fix this problem.

I've tried the following in my php.ini file:

```
open_basedir = /home/00000/domains
```

But still get the same error. Which is as follows:

```
Warning (2): file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/00000/domains/test.com/html/app/webroot/index.php/img/cameron.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/00000/domains) [APP/Plugin/Timthumb/Vendor/timthumb.php, line 896]
```

Any ideas?

The change is definitely being applied as the error path is updated to what I have specified above, but I still get the `open_basedir` restriction. And doing phpinfo() shows the change as well:

[image]

**Update: Media Temple doesn't offer support for this, but has been courtesy enough to provide some help and said that I need to do the following:**

```
open_basedir = "/home/00000/data/tmp:/home/00000/domains"
```

**However this STILL does not work! And they are unable to provide further info.**

**Update 2: Mod_rewrite is enabled, and I'm using this Plugin: https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin/**

Comment: Are you running without mod rewrite (please confirm by editing the question)? You look to have an application error, `File/(...index.php/attachments...` - the file `Plugin/Timthumb/Vendor/timthumb.php` is attempting to check if the _path_ `index.php/etc` exists in the webroot - it's not pointing at a writable path at all.

Comment: Mod_rewrite is enabled. And it's using CakePHP, and it does routing through that index.php as far as I know.

Comment: I've just been looking through all the code, and it looks like the Plugin itself is fine. But the Vendor Timthumb is struggling with the Front Controller in CakePHP. Do you know why?

Comment: I wrote my reply as an answer - know/recognise that it's just a normal PHP problem. You might be using CakePHP but there's no evidence that's a relevant factor to "the problem".

Answer (score 2):

You should leave the final trailing '/' off of your open_basedir. Per the docs:

> When you want to restrict access to only the specified directory, end with a slash. For example: open_basedir = /dir/incl/

So your entry only applies to /home/00000/domains, not any sub directories.

Comment: Are you sure the remote open_basedir is being set? If you run phpinfo(), do you see the value for open_basedir you are specifying?

Comment: I just noticed your path: html/app/webroot/index.php/img/cameron.jpg ... Is /index.php/img/ actually a directory?

Comment: Checked the phpinfo and the value has definitely being changed (although it looks like the master was correct in the first place). But still getting the error. Is the value incorrect?

Comment: The restriction specified with open_basedir is a directory name since PHP 5.2.16 and 5.3.4. Previous versions used it as a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't look like it has anything to do with the framework you're using - the vendor class raising the error doesn't depend on any (relevant) external configuration.

### There's a configuration or application error

But it's not the `open_basedir` settting. (which so long as it includes `/home/00000/domains/test.com/html/` should be no problem).

The [file raising the error](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin/blob/master/Vendor/timthumb.php#L896) is attempting to access a path that is (correctly) causing problems:

```
Warning (2): file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 

File(/home/00000/domains/test.com/html/app/webroot/index.php/attachments/view/5)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^

is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/00000/domains) 
[APP/Plugin/Timthumb/Vendor/timthumb.php, line 896
```

The path collides with a file, it's not possible to be a read/writable path even if open base dir were to permit it.

### Identify the reason

The [base path](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin/blob/master/Vendor/timthumb.php#L884) used is [derived from server variables](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin/blob/master/Vendor/timthumb.php#L824-L847) - does it contain `index.php`? :

```
protected function calcDocRoot(){
    $docRoot = @$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    if (defined('LOCAL_FILE_BASE_DIRECTORY')) {
        $docRoot = LOCAL_FILE_BASE_DIRECTORY;   
    }   
    if(!isset($docRoot)){ 
        $this->debug(3, "DOCUMENT_ROOT is not set. This is probably windows. Starting search 1.");
        if(isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])){
            $docRoot = str_replace( '\\', '/', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0-strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
            $this->debug(3, "Generated docRoot using SCRIPT_FILENAME and PHP_SELF as: $docRoot");
        }   
    }   
    if(!isset($docRoot)){ 
        $this->debug(3, "DOCUMENT_ROOT still is not set. Starting search 2.");
        if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])){
            $docRoot = str_replace( '\\', '/', substr(str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']), 0, 0-strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
            $this->debug(3, "Generated docRoot using PATH_TRANSLATED and PHP_SELF as: $docRoot");
        }   
    }   
    if($docRoot && $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] != '/'){ $docRoot = preg_replace('/\/$/', '', $docRoot); }
    $this->debug(3, "Doc root is: " . $docRoot);
    $this->docRoot = $docRoot;
}
```

If `index.php` doesn't come from the `docRoot` value - it's in the passed argument `$src`. Identify why or how `$src` contains an invalid path and correct the application code appropriately.

Comment: If I define it like so: http://pastebin.com/115qQq4W and do a debug and exit at the bottom. $docRoot is `'/home/00000/domains/test.com/html'`. So it's adding that index.php somewhere else outside of this function as this is the last part of the code.

Comment: Also I **can't** point to the webroot explicitly as the image might not live there... It only needs to go there for routing purposes.

Comment: If I do this: `$docRoot = $docRoot . '/app/webroot/';` I no longer get the open_basedir error. But I get `Could not find the internal image you specified.` error still. So it's still confused about how to get the image.

Comment: The image isn't inside `/app/webroot` but ALL routes go via the front controller in there.

Comment: In any case adding that line above, may remove the error, but it doesn't find the image, so I'd say it's not the right direction.